# How to center the images with the page tab?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, tabs

[image]

How can I center those images with the tab? Currently I am simply adding the images and letting the text property blank.

Comment: I think this is by design and it looks not bad to me if not wanting to say it's OK. Why do you want it to be centered while it looks OK? You may have to draw the image yourself.

Comment: I want it centered because it is weird the other way. People don't like it and neither do I.

Comment: why not add extra space to the image on the left size?

Comment: or get rid of all extra white space and resize the image to fit the tab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out-of-the-box it can't be done. You can try creating a custom control derived from TabControl which does something like this:

```
public class BrunoTabControl : TabControl
{
    protected override void OnDrawItem(System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ImageList == null) return;
        int imageIndex = TabPages[e.Index].ImageIndex;
        if (imageIndex >= 0) ImageList.Draw(e.Graphics, 0, 0, imageIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Even changing the values from 0 to 10, or 20 the images just won't dislocate.

Comment: Are you by any chance using TabSizeMode.Fixed?

Comment: I just had to change the `DrawMode` property to `OwnerDraw` it worked, just had to do some minor changes to the coordinates. Although I got some dark shadow borders on the tabs, there is any way to remove it?

Comment: Without a completely custom drawn control, no. That said, there's other alternatives you can try like hiding the tabs completely and using a series of buttons to toggle between the tabpages. If the tab button style is really that much of a big deal you might be better off looking at a third party control suite like DevExpress (budget allowing of course).